# Step Definitions are not recognized while running cucumber tests from command prompt

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

While I run cucumber tests from IntelliJ IDE, it works perfectly.

However when I try to run it from command prompt, after creating a runner class, the step definitions are not recognized.

Below is how the code looks like:

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        glue={"classpath:src\\test\\java"},
        features = "src\\test\\resources",
        plugin={"pretty","html:target/site/cucumber-pretty","json:target/cucumber.json"})

public class RunCucumberTests {

}
```

Below is how the project structure looks like. The 'LoginSeps' class contains the step definitions.

[image]

The error which is thrown is as below

[ERROR] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 5, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.79 s <<< FAILURE! - in RunCucumberTests
[ERROR] Login functionality.Login Successful  Time elapsed: 0.276 s  <<< ERROR!
io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException:
The step 'I am in the login page of application' and 2 other step(s) are undefined.....

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Try by chaining `glue={"classpath:src\\test\\java"}` to `glue={"src\\test\\java"}`

Comment: @NandanA, I tired changing as above. But it throws the same error.  

[ERROR] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 5, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.79 s <<< FAILURE! - in RunCucumberTests
[ERROR] Login functionality.Login Successful  Time elapsed: 0.276 s  <<< ERROR!
io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException:
The step 'I am in the login page of application' and 2 other step(s) are undefined.

Comment: While I run cucumber tests from IntelliJ IDE, it works perfectly. --> Haven't you run by runner class in intellij?

Comment: Try this `glue={"LoginSteps"}`  In glue, we should give the stepDefinitions package or class name.

Comment: Thank you @NandanA. It worked. Based on your suggestion above, I created a package and moved the step definitions class to that package. Then I referred the package (containing step definition) in the glue.

Comment: I will post an answer please accept if it helps:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stepdefiniton` classes should always reside in a package and under `src\test\java` folder.

Please create a package `cucumberStep` or something and move the class `LoginSteps` under that.

**Code**:

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "src\\test\\resources\\features", glue = { "cucumberStep", }, dryRun = false, plugin = { "pretty",
        "html:report/TestReport.html", }, monochrome = true, stepNotifications = true, tags = "@Regression")
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved with a bit of refactoring.

Moving the step definitions class to a new package and referring the package name in the glue resolved the issue.

Below is how the solution looks now.

[image]